# How do I override the url field when extending a base model in Extjs?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am new to Extjs and am following an Extjs 5 example on creating a model hierarchy:
(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/data_package.html)

I created a base model which holds a proxy with a url field. I now want to extend this base model and only override the url part below:

```
Ext.define('MyPortal.model.Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        }],
        schema: {
            namespace: 'MyPortal.model',  // generate auto entityName
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax'
                ,url : '/portal-web/{entityName}'
                ,reader: {  
                    type:'json',              
                    rootProperty:'{entityName:lowercase}',
                    idProperty: 'id'
                }
            }
        }   
    });
```

Here is a child model:

```
Ext.define('MyPortal.model.Account', {
        extend   : 'MyPortal.model.Base'
        ,fields: [
            {name: 'accountId',  type: 'string'},
            {name: 'name',  type: 'string'}
        ]
        , //add something here to override the url from the base model above?
    });
```

I tried adding a url field or function to the child model, but these are ignored. Is it possible for a child model to override the parent's url param?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`proxy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.schema.Schema-cfg-proxy) option in the `schema` is what Ext5 calls an [`ObjectTemplate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.util.ObjectTemplate). Simply put, it is used as a default configuration for the models of the schema.

You can override this defaults in the `proxy` configuration of the model itself (one proxy instance will be created **by model class** -- not by model instance). Note that the [model class](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model) itself doesn't accept an `url` option, it must be set in the [`proxy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-proxy).

For you, that would give something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyPortal.model.Account', {
    extend   : 'MyPortal.model.Base' // I guess you had a typo here
    ,fields: [
        {name: 'accountId',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
    ]
    // Override proxy URL (the other options of the schema's proxy
    // will be used)
    ,proxy {
        url: 'path/to/accounts'
    }
});
```

FYI, the reader doesn't have an `idProperty` option (so says [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json)), it's [in the model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty) this time...

Comment: Worked like a charm and thanks for the background info!

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different problem:  my data model is generated, so i am using override: to extend model classes like this:

```
Ext.define('app.override.Foo', {
    override: 'app.data.Foo',
    proxy: {url: 'rest/foo',type: 'rest'}
}
```

this proxy override does not take effect in extjs 5 (works great in 4.x)

Comment: I figured it out, you have to use a third argument which is a function that gets called after the class is created and call this.setProxy(..)